# Word frequency in Solr

Tags: java, solr, word-frequency

I am trying to get frequency of words using solr. When I give this query :

```
localSolr/solr/select?q=someQuery&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=content&wt=xml
```

solr gives me the frequencies like;

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="content">
<int name="word1">24</int>
<int name="word2">12</int>
<int name="word3">8</int>
```

But when I count the words; I find that word2's actual count number is 13. Solr counts same words in the field as one.

For example;

field text consists; `word2 word5 word7 word9 word2`. Solr doesn't return word2's count number 2 instead it returns 1. It returns 1 for the count of word2 for the both sentences below;

```
word2 word10 word11 word12
word2 word9 word7 word2 word23
```

So frequencies return wrongly. I have checked facet fields but didn't find the proper parameter for that. How can I fix it so that it counts same words in sentence?

edit : 
relevant part of schema.xml :

```
<fieldType name="text_tr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <field name="content" type="text_tr" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
    <field name="text" type="text_tr" stored="false" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the field you're faceting on is multivalued, then each word in the facet gets the proper count

i forgot to mention one thing: [Term Vector Component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent) will get you where you need

in the query, **tv.tf** will give you the term frequency for each term, while **tv.fl** tells solr on which fields the frequency should be calculated

**NB** this makes your indexing time slower than now (aka: you have to try it)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have changed field to make multivalued parameter true but it still returns the wrong answer.

Comment: can you post your schema.xml, so maybe i can give you more info?

Comment: Sorry I cannot put all the schema.xml but I edited and put the relevant part. I hope it helps.

Comment: Nice explanation there

Comment: @Samuele and yns I know its been a while you asked/answered this question but I have similar problem and I followed the guidelines in TermVectorComponent but I can't figure out what to change in the http request that is shown in yns question after setting up TermVectorComponent for 'text' field?

Answer (score 0):

Use the luke request handler

`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/luke?fl=YOUR_TEXT_FIELD&numTerms=500`

more info: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler