# Number of matched tokens in Solr Query

Tags: solr, lucene

How can I find out, how many of the terms in my query actually matched? I know that the scoring ranks documents higher that have more matches, but I would like to know how many actually did match.

Say, my query is

```
weekday:(monday tuesday wednesday)
```

I would like to know how many terms did actually match, so I can highlight results that matched all terms and mark results that match only partially.

I don't need a total count, only how many query terms matched.

- If the document is "monday, monday", the matched count should be 1 (not 2)
- If the document is "monday through friday", the matched count should be 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try using tv.tf in your query for term frequency. see this:[for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031534/word-frequency-in-solr)

Comment: Since the documentation link for the Term Vector Component in the link above is unavailable due to the Solr Wiki being down. Here is an alternate like to Term Vector Component documentation - http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component

Comment: The link has changed https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component