# word frequency out of contents field from result documents

Tags: spring, solr, word-frequency

I am very new to spring-data Solr. I need your help.
I got a result `CrawlDocument(Bean)` list composing of id, contents and title filed.
I want to display word frequency count from contents field of result document list.

```
SimpleFacetQuery facetQuery = new SimpleFacetQuery(new
Criteria(CrawlDocument.FIELD_CONTENT).contains(searchStr));
```

Can you guys give any tips or examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031534/word-frequency-in-solr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688459/solr-term-frequency